# Auto iterator in vector

Tags: c++

Why the auto keyword is not working...????

```
s.push_back(11);
s.push_back(22);
s.push_back(33);
s.push_back(55);

for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++){
    cout << (*it) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=C++11`?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 3):

It should work. You need C++11 support for this. On GCC, you need version 4.4 or higher, and make sure to use the `std=c++0x` flag (or possibly `std=c++11` for the newest versions).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if your compiler supports the auto keyword as it was officialy introduced in the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 1):

You need Visual Studio 2010 (or higher) or the GCC flag `-std=c++11` to compile this. You could also rewrite this into a for-range loop in VC++11 or GCC 4.6 and higher.

```
for(auto& it : s) {
    std::cout << it << '\n';
}
```

Comment: VC++ 2010 supports `auto` as well.

Comment: @ildjarn I thought it was the older version of auto. I'll edit my post though.

Comment: VC++ 10 does not support the for-range though.